# Save object name into ForeignKey field on child object - Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have these models:

```
class MyModel1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    fieldrelated1 = models.OneToOneField('MyModel2', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, related_name='mymodel2')
    fieldrelated2 = models.OneToOneField('MyModel3', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, related_name='mymodel3')
    fieldrelated3 = models.OneToOneField('MyModel4', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, related_name='mymodel4')

class MyModel2(models.Model):
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    myfk = models.ForeignKey(MyModel1, max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)

class MyModel3(models.Model):
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    test = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)

class MyModel4(models.Model):
    field4 = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    test = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
```

Then, this method:

```
def create_child_objects(instance, created, rad, **kwargs):
    if not created or rad:
        return
        field1 = instance.field1

    if not instance.fieldrelated1_id:
        fieldrelated1, _ = MyModel2.objects.get_or_create(field1=field2)
    instance.fieldrelated1 = fieldrelated1

    if not instance.fieldrelated2_id:
        fieldrelated2, _ = MyModel3.objects.get_or_create(field1=field3)
    instance.fieldrelated2 = fieldrelated2

    if not instance.fieldrelated3_id:
        fieldrelated3, _ = MyModel4.objects.get_or_create(field1=field4)
    instance.fieldrelated3 = fieldrelated3

    instance.save()

models.signals.post_save.connect(create_child_records, sender=MyModel1, dispatch_uid='create_child_objects')
```

So far, this method works to save the parent and save particular fields on child creation.

My problem comes when I want to, for example, instead of saving a parent's `CharField` into a child `CharField`, I want to save the actual parent instance into a child's `ForeignKey` field, like this:

```
def create_child_objects(instance, created, rad, **kwargs):
    if not created or rad:
        return
    field1 = instance.__str__

    if not instance.fieldrelated1_id:
        fieldrelated1, _ = MyModel2.objects.get_or_create(field1=myfk)
    instance.fieldrelated1 = fieldrelated1

    if not instance.fieldrelated2_id:
        fieldrelated2, _ = MyModel3.objects.get_or_create(field1=field3)
    instance.fieldrelated2 = fieldrelated2

    if not instance.fieldrelated3_id:
        fieldrelated3, _ = MyModel4.objects.get_or_create(field1=field4)
    instance.fieldrelated3 = fieldrelated3

    instance.save()

models.signals.post_save.connect(create_child_objects, sender=MyModel1, dispatch_uid='create_child_records')
```

The parent object is saved into db with a method like this:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return ('{}: {}: {}'.format(self.field1, self.field2, self.field3))
```

So, after the second `create_child_objects` it throws me this:

```
TypeError at /admin/mymodel/instance/add/
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'method'
```

So, how can I save the parent object descriptor into a `ForeignKey` field to the parent object?

**EDIT**

What is saved on this `myfk` field is the id of `MyModel1`, so, it would be sufficient to save this, but when I try like this `field1 = MyModel1.id`

It says:

```
ValueError at /admin/mymodel/instance/add/
Cannot assign "98": "MyModel2.field1.id" must be a "MyModel1" instance.
```

Comment: I think it should be `__str__()`

Comment: You always "save the actual parent instance into a child's ForeignKey field", at least in Django code. At the db level, what gets saved is the parent's primary key. The string representation of the parent has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
field1 = instance.__str__
```

change to

```
field1 = instance.__str__()
```

or

```
field1 = str(instance)
```

`__str__` is a method so your assignment makes `field1` pointing to this method, not method's result.

## UPD

All the `MyModel[2-4].objects.get_or_create(field1=field2)` lines are wrong:

- those model don't have `field1` field, so correct filter would be `field[2-4]=field1`
- anyway, I assume it will never match anything because `__str__` method is a combination of those IDs and this string must be parsed first; only extracted values would match

And I don't understand how your `__str__` method works since this model does not have `field2`, `field3` and `field4`.

I suggest you to rethink the approach. Have a look at [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

Comment: Hi, nice explanation, thank you very much, but sorry, it says invalid literal for int() with base 10, when I save the parent object with __str__ method, it has a combination of numbers and strings, (field1, field2, field3) could that be the issue?

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you so much, I did some queries on the db, what needs to be stored is the actual 'id' on the 'myfk' field, it should display it, I've edited my question, if you fancy, thank you.

Comment: Your obfuscated(?) code and error messages do not match.

Comment: I mean, if I add the 'instance' id, which would be the MyModel1 id, it should be saved as such, I don't understand why this error, seems like I have to declare the MyModel1 instance explicitly